# Why I need any type in typescript?

Tags: .net, typescript, methods, return-type, any

We have a simple method in typescript

```
function identity(arg) {
    return arg;
}
```

This method gives a parameter and returns it and it will work by any type (int,string,bool and more).
We can also declare this method in another way:

```
 function identity(arg:any):any {
        return arg;
    }
```

This method gives a parameter and returns it and it will work by any type (int,string,bool and more).

What is the difference between the two ways? In other word what is benefit using of `any` type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your particular case, it doesn't matter. **But**

- If you have the strict flag on (or, by extension, the noImplicitAny flag), it will throw an error for the first, but not the second. Because an *implicit* any is not allowed.
- The reason they are the same is because TypeScript can't infer the type of the argument or the return type, so they are both inferred to any.

Any is your escape hatch from TypeScript, it means "I don't know what type this is, so anything I do with it is acceptable, any property on it implicitly exists (and also has a type of any), I can call it with any parameters, and I can also `new` it.

It is recommended that you minimize your use of `any`s, implicit or explicit, because then you lose some of the benefit that TypeScript affords.

Answer (score 0):

`any` is **like** an anonymous type, not like `Object`. When using `any`, the compiler does minimal type checking since it doesn't know your variable's members.

Example:

```
var var1: any;
var var2: Object;

var1.whatever(); // The compiler trusts you
var2.whatever(); // Compiler throws an error
```

As you can see in the example, you can handle `var1` however you want, but you can't mess with `var2` except for its official members.

In your function, you can whatever you want with your `arg`, but if you specify a type for it then you'll be bound to use that type's members.

Comment: The type system is structural so the concept of anonymity doesn't really apply. Also the other type is considered bad practice to use. Use `{}`

Comment: Notice the bold **like**. And even tho Object might be bad practice, its the simpliest thing to use when trying to explain something.

Comment: that's still confusing. I think you meant Dynamic type which is all so confusing but not as incorrect